# how to download videos using phonegab in iphone?

Tags: iphone, cordova

This is first time I am using iphone app using phonegap, I want to download videos from server, now how to do this using phonegap?
any suggestion or help?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look a this plugin :

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1097750723/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url